# "Не" вместе или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, частица-не

Дальнейшую дискуссию считаю не целесообразной.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Лучше слитно. Отрицания нет. Считаю излишней, зряшной, пустой тратой времени и т.п.

Хотите отрицать – пишите "не считаю целесообразной".